# Wagtail on webfaction

Tags: wagtail

I can't seem to get image uploads to work in my webfaction install. I created a virtualenv and used the pip install command to install everything. The admin site works great and the site displays but I can't upload images. I get this in the logs.

ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Does the error mention a specific file? Can you add the complete traceback? 'pip install command to install everything' what is everything? Shouldn't you install Pillow also?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the Pillow image-handling library has failed to install correctly. There are a couple of non-Python dependencies - libjpeg and zlib - which you may be missing: see https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#external-libraries for details. Once you have these installed, reinstall with `pip uninstall Pillow` then `pip install Pillow`, and check the output for any further error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, although I had a python3 virtualenv set up, I had an alias to python 2.7 set in my bash profile and it wasn’t using the right python.